# How do I use a USB joystick to generate MIDI data to control audio apps?

Tags: sound, hardware, midi

I've read about people hacking joysticks to make a foot controller for audio apps by wiring up some robust switches to the circuit board. It's probably possible to do something with the joystick too.

I'm just wondering how you would convert this to MIDI as I assume this is what the apps will expect.

Or can you map the switches to keyboard commands for similar effect?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, consider posting it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Something to try](http://lsmi-all.sourceforge.net/)

Its been a long time since I've played with anything like this.  If you lucky, your software will allow direct input from /dev/input0 (or whichever your joystick is)

Good luck.